# Cakephp Import Controller

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am new in cakephp and I want to import controller in my controller so i use the below syntax. This is my controller in which I import user controller:

**users_controller.php**

```
 function api_work(){ $data = $this->User->find('all'); $this->set('data' , $data); }
```

**plays_controller.php**

```
    function api_show()
        {
            $this->layout= false;
            App::import('Controller', 'Users');
            $Users = new UsersController;
            $Users->constructClasses();
            $data = $Users->api_work();
            pr($data); //it not display anything and shows error like undefined varia
ble
        }
```

Controller is successfully imported.
Question is how can I data return from api_work() function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CakePHP is a MVC (Model View Controller). The api_work function in users_controller should instead be in the User model (User.php). Alternatively you could do `$this->User->find('all');` in the plays_controller.php instead of `$Users->api_work()`.

Above suggestion means you would need to remove all these lines:

```
App::import('Controller', 'Users');
$Users = new UsersController;
$Users->constructClasses();
```

You will also need to make sure that you add the following at the top of users_controller.php (just under the class declaration).

```
$uses = array([...], 'User'); OR $uses = array('User');
```

I really recommend reading the CakePHP book ( http://book.cakephp.org/ ).

Comment: thanks for reply its really helpfull to me. but can you tell me how can i  use the method of one controller in other controller except this method.

Comment: The only way is using requestAction. I however strongly recommend not using it. It's an extremely bad practice especially when it's something that could be easily be done by doing $this->User->findAll() within the plays_controller. However if you insist: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/991/requestAction